# Why doesn't mono have a culture info when running through upstart?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, upstart

I have a daemon built using c# and mono. When testing and running the daemon and launching via the command line, the threads culture info is properly filled in with "en-US". However, when starting the same exact process through Ubuntu upstart, the threads culture info is always an empty string. This makes my currency conversions extremely weird. Whats the difference?

I should mention that I am getting the culture by using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name` and simply setting the culture to "en-US" in the code on my own does fix the issue. I am more or less trying to understand WHY this behavior is happening.

Comment: Can you show the exact code giving this issue? Do you mean `Thread.CurrentCulture.Name`?

Comment: Seems you will need to set the culture manually in your code.  You could pass in a culture through the command line, and use that.